# Controlling the colors of rows in ggplot table annotation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to color the rows of an annotation table in a plot that looks something like this:

Make up some data:

```
mydf<-data.frame(y=runif(300,-1,1))
mydf$name<-sample(c("a","b"),300, replace=T)
mydf$rank<-rank(mydf$y)
colvec<-c(a="darkseagreen",b="darkorchid")

### annotation table
annot.tbl<-data.frame(table(mydf$name))
colnames(annot.tbl)<-c("name","freq")
```

**plot**

```
ggplot(mydf)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=rank, y=y, fill=name), stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colvec)+
  annotate(geom="table", x=0, y=max(mydf$y), label=list(annot.tbl))
```

Up until here it all works fine but now I figured it might look better if the table rows were colored correspondingly to the legend in the plot. Just to "draw the eye" and stuff XD

```
ggplot(mydf)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=rank, y=y, fill=name), stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colvec)+
  annotate(geom="table", x=0, y=max(mydf$y), label=list(annot.tbl), fill=c("darkseagreen", "darkorchid"))
```

Somehow I though the solution could be this simple, but no, the entire table is filled "darkorchid" or whatever color is last.

How can I make the row fill correspond to the legend?

UPDATE: I now have a table with the correct row colors... But no idea how to add it to the plot, just executing the code plots it in the middle right where I can't use it...

```
ggplot(mydf)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=rank, y=y, fill=name), stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colvec)
  grid.table(annot.tbl, rows=NULL, theme=ttheme_default(core=list(bg_params=list(fill=c("darkseagreen","darkorchid")))))
```

Comment: You could stick with your approach via annotate and pass your table theme to the `table.theme` parameter, i.e. `annotate(geom = "table", x = 0, y = max(mydf$y), label = list(annot.tbl), table.theme = myttheme)` where `mytheme <- theme_default(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your most recent update, it seems that you just need to move the position of the table that is currently positioned in the middle of your plot. You can move it using `pushViewport()`

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydf)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=rank, y=y, fill=name), stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colvec) 
pushViewport(viewport(y=.25,height=.5))
grid.table(annot.tbl, rows=NULL, theme=ttheme_default(core=list(bg_params=list(fill=c("darkseagreen","darkorchid")))))
```

[image: example]