# Colour rows by one factor in geom_table

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a ggplot2 graph in which I have a "classic" dot plot together with a table.
This is an example of the plot I am making:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
mtcars[1:10,] %>%
  select(cyl, mpg, wt) -> tb

df <- tibble(x = 5.45, y = 34, tb = list(tb))

# using defaults
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_table(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = tb))
```

This is the output of the code:
[image]

I would however the rows of the table be coloured according to the factor `cyl`. So every rows which has `carb`==4 is red, ==6 is green and ==8 is blue.
I don't need the column `cyl` to appear in the table, so that can be removed (if possible).
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance for your precious help,
Luca

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most of the ggplot ecosystem, you can't just use a fill aesthetic inside `geom_table`, and instead need to create a table theme which gets passed to `table.theme` inside `geom_table`. This means it is somewhat inconvenient to achieve the desired effect, but it is possible with something like the following:

```r
thm <- gridExtra::ttheme_default()
fills <- scales::hue_pal()(3)[as.numeric(factor(df$tb[[1]]$cyl))]
thm$core$bg_params$fill <- fills
df$tb[[1]] <- df$tb[[1]][-1]

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_table(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = tb), table.theme = thm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hacky, but using the `table.theme` argument, you can supply the table with your own background colors (see [Controlling the colors of rows in ggplot table annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70035033/controlling-the-colors-of-rows-in-ggplot-table-annotation)).

First, we construct a vector which contains a required background color for each row. Then, we use those colors in the `table.theme` argument of `geom_table`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
mtcars[1:10,] %>%
    select(cyl, mpg, wt) -> tb

df <- tibble(x = 5.45, y = 34, tb = list(tb))

# Construct vector of required background colors (from default ggplot2 theme)
colors <- scales::hue_pal()(n_distinct(tb$cyl))
colors <- colors[factor(tb$cyl)]

# using defaults
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_table(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = tb),
               table.theme = gridExtra::ttheme_default(core = list(bg_params=list(fill=colors))))
```