# How to plot a table reflecting gene sequencing data qualitatively

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, plot, sequencing

I'm looking for ways to plot sequencing data like this:
[image: from Nature Medicine]

It seems to be a common plot. I know there are ways to plot a table filled with colors from a relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300236/colour-rows-by-one-factor-in-geom-table)

```
tableplot <- function(ret, nrow, ncol, main){
    m <- matrix(as.integer(ret$y),nrow,ncol)
    image(1:nrow,1:ncol,m,col=c("grey","green"),axes=FALSE, xlab="gene",ylab="sample",main=main) 
    text(row(m),col(m),labels=matrix(ret$x,nrow,ncol))
}
ret <- data.frame("x" = c("1-gene1","1-gene2","2-gene1","2-gene2"), "y" = c(1,1,0,1)) #0 is loss, 1 is gain.
tableplot(ret, 2, 2, "My tests")
```

I also found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506324/split-fill-in-ggplot-geom-tile-or-heatmap-two-colors-by-third-value) with the last answer geomSplitTile giving a plot on the right direction, but I failed to comprehend the code.

Comment: Write a script. [ask]

Comment: @AathilAhamed please don't encourage blantanly off-topic unanswerable questions by upvoting theme. New joiner or not.

Comment: I helped them exactly how you said by pointing them to [ask] (which they should have already read as prompted when they joined).